# Log Api Gateway request/response body/headers to ElasticSearch

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-elasticsearch, amazon-cloudwatch

It's easy to setup it by default, but i cannot change the format of messages. It sends to CloudWatch

Api Gateway works as proxy

> 2019-03-15 13:31:22.248 (REQ_ID) Method completed with status: 200
>
> 2019-03-15 13:31:22.248 (REQ_ID) Successfully completed execution
>
> 2019-03-15 13:31:22.248 (REQ_ID) Method response headers:
>   {Cache-Control=max-age=0, private, must-revalidate,
>   Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8, Date=Fri, 15 Mar 2019
>   13:31:22 GMT, ETag=W/"607046c7bacdeee5e27e99f48fa2e053",
>   Server=nginx/1.12.1 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.60, Status=200 OK,
>   Vary=Accept-Encoding, Origin, X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff,
>   X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN, X-Powered-By=Phusion Passenger 4.0.60,
>   X-Request-Id=88c8f3c2-0a25-4445-9010-30d4753b855a, X-Runtime=0.030736,
>   X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block, Connection=keep-alive}
>
> 2019-03-15 13:31:22.248 (REQ_ID) Method response body after
>   transformations: {"success":1,"message":"Token is invalid"}
>
> 2019-03-15 13:31:22.248 (REQ_ID) Endpoint response headers:
>   {Cache-Control=max-age=0, private, must-revalidate,
>   Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8, Date=Fri, 15 Mar 2019
>   13:31:22 GMT, ETag=W/"607046c7bacdeee5e27e99f48fa2e053",
>   Server=nginx/1.12.1 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.60, Status=200 OK,
>   Vary=Accept-Encoding, Origin, X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff,
>   X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN, X-Powered-By=Phusion Passenger 4.0.60,
>   X-Request-Id=88c8f3c2-0a25-4445-9010-30d4753b855a, X-Runtime=0.030736,
>   X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block, transfer-encoding=chunked,
>   Connection=keep-alive}
>
> 2019-03-15 13:31:22.248 (REQ_ID) Endpoint response body before
>   transformations: {"success":1,"message":"Token is invalid"}
>
> 2019-03-15 13:31:22.248 (REQ_ID) Received response. Integration
>   latency: 43 ms
>
> 2019-03-15 13:31:22.205 (REQ_ID) Sending request to
>   https://proxy.domain.com/api/endpoint
>
> 2019-03-15 13:31:22.205 (REQ_ID) Endpoint request body after
>   transformations: {"message":"hello world"}
>
> 2019-03-15 13:31:22.205 (REQ_ID) Endpoint request headers:
>   {x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=API, User-Agent=curl/7.54.0,
>   X-Forwarded-Proto=https, X-Forwarded-For=195.24.159.254,
>   content-type=application/json, X-Forwarded-Port=443,
>   X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5c8ba92a-7fb7fa94b9991bb8f1561d55, accept=*/*}
>
> 2019-03-15 13:31:22.205 (REQ_ID) Endpoint request URI:
>   https://proxy.domain.com/api/endpoint
>
> 2019-03-15 13:31:22.119 (REQ_ID) Method request body before
>   transformations: {"message":"hello world"}
>
> 2019-03-15 13:31:22.119 (9f76246a-4726-11e9-a18d-25bda2ff1f7b) Method
>   request headers: {User-Agent=curl/7.54.0, X-Forwarded-Proto=https,
>   X-Forwarded-For=195.24.159.254, content-type=application/json,
>   Host=api.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, X-Forwarded-Port=443,
>   X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5c8ba92a-7fb7fa94b9991bb8f1561d55, accept=*/*}
>
> 2019-03-15 13:31:22.119 (REQ_ID) Method request query string: {}
>
> 2019-03-15 13:31:22.119 (REQ_ID) Method request path:
>   {proxy=api/endpoint}

I need to send in JSON these 4 columns only: request_header, request_body, response_header, response_body to ES. Now it sends all the logs above for each request.

Comment: Maybe not the same platform but with NGINX, editing log-format-upstream allow to setup the log format. With fluentbit collector, you have to set a json parser in INPUT in fluent-bit.conf. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Are you sending from API Gateway to lambda and from lambda to es?